# Pass jQuery data from View to Controller and save it as many-to-many

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a many to many relationship. I generated controller and view for the 2 below entities (Product and Invoice) from scaffolding in asp.net 3.0 and ef core 3.1

I'm able to do CRUD from both entities.

In Invoice View page I need to have a Dropdown that is fed from Product table and add ItemName into the dropdownlist.
I did it already thru ViewData["Products"] and it works fine.

When user selects from that dropdownlist, there an 'Add item' button next to it,
if the user click on that '*Add item*'  button, the item name must be added below on the page. I did it already thru jquery and its works

The page has a Save button at the bottom, when clicked, it's only pass the Invoice model to the controller thru Binding (it's the correct behavior),
but I'm not sure how to pass all the added items (only their Id) to the controller to be saved in the join-table (ProductInvoice).

Not sure maybe I did not design the architecture of the application properly that's why I wrote the whole scenario/use-case maybe you can suggest me to redesign.

**In brief, the use-case is : user must add itemName (fetch from Product table) to the invoice and save it as many-to-many relationship.**

**How to save all the ItemId that I added on Invoice page, save them to ProductInvoice table as many-to-many,

How to pass them to the controller from the view ?**

I searched the whole day, I couldn't find how to do it that's the reason of my post.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }    
    public IList<ProductInvoice> ProductInvoices { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductInvoice> ProductInvoices { get; set; }
}
    
public class ProductInvoice
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("InvoiceId,InvoiceDate")] Invoice invoice)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(invoice);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(invoice);
}


<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var totalInvoice = 0;

            $("#btn-add-item").click(function () {

                var selectedItem = $('#SelectedProducts :selected').text();
                var getCostPerItem = $('#SelectedProducts :selected').val();

                getCostPerItem = getCostPerItem.split("-")[1];
                getCostPerItem = getCostPerItem.split(".")[0];
                totalInvoice = parseInt(totalInvoice) + parseInt(getCostPerItem);

                $('<div id="created_div">' + '<b>+</b> ' + selectedItem + ' :  $ ' + ' ' + getCostPerItem + '<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-remove-item float-right">Remove</a></div><br>').insertAfter('#main-body-card');
                $("#total-invoice-input").val(totalInvoice);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi @CodingValue, please share your whole razor view. Besides, there is no such `CreatedDate`, `CreateByUser` and `TotalInvoice` in your `Invoice ` model, so the model binding system will not succeed.

Comment: @Rena I modified the Create argument to match the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductInvoice> ProductInvoices { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductInvoice> ProductInvoices { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInvoice
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

View:

Firstly, the Product dropdownlist value is the `ProductId` and text is `ItemName` in my project.

Then, to pass the related `ProductId` and add to the `Invoice` model, you need add hidden (or not) input which name is like:`ProductInvoices[index].ProductId`.

Fianally, the params in Bind attribute(`[Bind("InvoiceId,CreatedDate,CreateByUser,TotalInvoice")]`) must match the model `Invoice`.

```
@model Invoice    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div id="main-body-card"></div>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="InvoiceDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="InvoiceDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="InvoiceDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select id="SelectedProducts"  asp-items="(SelectList)@ViewData["Products"]"></select>
                <button type="button" id="btn-add-item">Add</button>
            </div>
            <label>total: </label><input id="total-invoice-input" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>      
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var totalInvoice = 0;
            var i = 0;      //add this...
            $("#btn-add-item").click(function () {    
                var selectedItem = $('#SelectedProducts :selected').text();
                var getCostPerItem = $('#SelectedProducts :selected').val();            
                totalInvoice = parseInt(totalInvoice) + parseInt(getCostPerItem);   
                $('<div id="created_div">' + '<b>+</b> ' + selectedItem + ' :  $ ' + ' ' + getCostPerItem + '<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-remove-item float-right">Remove</a></div><br>').insertAfter('#main-body-card');
                //add this....
                $("<input value='"+getCostPerItem+"' name='ProductInvoices[" + i + "].ProductId' hidden/>").insertAfter('#created_div');
                $("#total-invoice-input").val(totalInvoice);
                i++;   //add this...
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewData["Products"] = new SelectList(_context.Product.ToList(), "ProductId", "ItemName");
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("InvoiceId,InvoiceDate,ProductInvoices")] Invoice invoice)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(invoice);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(invoice);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanls for helping. My code is working fine. I was stuck on : **How to save all the ItemId that I added on Invoice page, save them to ProductInvoice table as many-to-many ?

How to pass them (all the ItemId) from the view to the controller in order to be saved in ProductInvoice as many-to-many**.  I'm able to save the Invoice properly, but it doesn't save the ProductInvoice (ProductId, InvoiceId).

Comment: Hi @CodingValue, Please check my code. It works well to save them to ProductInvoice table as many-to-many.

Comment: Thanks. Let me take a look and will get back to you soon.

Comment: In the meantime, how do I pass 3 values (Product model) from the controller  (Create method) to the SelectList (Dropdownlist)?   as the SelectList can only accept 2 (value and text)

Comment: Hi @CodingValue, If the original issue solved, please accept as answer. If have another issue, please post a new thread and share detailed code and explanation.

Comment: cool. let me change my code to reflect your solution then, will create another post.

Comment: Ok. waiting for your response.

Comment: I added the code, when I run to test it, the **ProductInvoices** in Create Method, Bind attribute show null.  But On the browser I can see it creates the hidden field properly.  By the way, in the **Model invoice** I don't have a property called *ProductInvoices*. Do I need to add it ?

Comment: I'm getting null value in _ProductInvoices_ parameters, in Invoice controller, Create POST Method.

Comment: I fixed Null value from ProductInvoices paramater. I was missing one thing.

Comment: A new issue occurred. I'm getting *Price* value instead of real *ProductId* in ProductInvoices parameter of Create POST method.